# Kendo NumericTextbox: Restrict user from entering certain number of decimal places

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have a numeric textbox like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model).Format("c").Decimals(2).Spinners(false))
```

But this still allows the user to enter more than 2 decimal places in edit mode
which gets rounded up or down when it loses focus. (i.e 13.126 turns to 13.13)

1) Is there a way to stop the user from entering more than 2 decimal values in edit mode

2) Prevent the automatic rounding from happening (so if a 13.126 is entered it stays as 13.12)

Comment: you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21126426/2001735

Answer (score 0):

try with `Round(false)`

ex:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(
   model => model).Format("c").Decimals(2).Round(false).Spinners(false)
)
```